# GNOME3: What's the path of gnome run dialog (ALT + F2)?

Tags: command-line, gnome3, run-dialog

If I type "touch test" on run dialog it does not create any file on my home folder, so I was wondering where these files are created since I can do some dangerous things like fallocate or dd some really big files that I will not find later.

Comment: Run `pwd > /tmp/gnomepwd.txt`.

Comment: @IporSircer Well, this does not write anything to `/tmp` in my case. Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, `touch test` creates a file `test` in my home directory.

Running `pwd > /tmp/gnomepwd.txt` does not generate a file. The run dialog is not your shell. It just sees `pwd`, `>` and `/tmp/gnomepwd.txt`, runs `pwd` and passes the two other strings as arguments. `pwd` does not take arguments, only options, so happily prints the current directory to nowhere.

Running `sh -c "pwd > /tmp/gnomepwd.txt"` will start a shell, which will interpret the command `pwd` and `>` as the redirection symbol. This time, you will find the output in a file, the current folder of Gnome Shell, which is the home folder of the current user.

To do "dangerous things", you need to be root, so precede your command with `su` or `sudo`. If you do dangerous things, it is wise to know exactly what you will be doing by specifying an absolute path instead of a relative path. Anyway, better is not to use the Alt+F2 prompt for administrator tasks. Prefer then to act as a pro and open a terminal instead.